# почему не работают функции javascript?

Tags: javascript

Только начал учить javascript. Может кто-нибудь знает, почему не работают функции javascript? 
Беру функцию отсюда --> http://mathhelpplanet.com/static.php в разделе Алгоритмы на JavaScript. 
Создаю док. в формате .js, вставляю туда функцию, открываю через ссылку в док-те формата .html, также заранее созданном. Но ничего не выводит. В чём конкретно может быть проблема?

Comment: код покажи. наверняка какая-нибудь скобка лишняя

Comment: function BubbleSort(A)       // A - массив, который нужно
{                            // отсортировать по возрастанию.
    var n = A.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
     { for (var j = 0; j < n-1-i; j++)
        { if (A[j+1] < A[j])
           { var t = A[j+1]; A[j+1] = A[j]; A[j] = t; }
        }
     }                     
    return A;    // На выходе сортированный по возрастанию массив A.
}

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает. Массив правильно передаёшь? Вот тут смотри.
https://playcode.io/534172